# pandas.errors.parsererror error tokenizing data. c error expected 2 fields?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, keras, split

I am using a code from this github repository [code](https://github.com/kenshohara/3D-ResNets-PyTorch/blob/master/util_scripts/ucf101_json.py)
the main idea is to convert txt files to json format file

I start running the code it suppose to read thefile and then convert it but I got the above error.
that's snippet from the code where the error occures

```py
def convert_csv_to_dict(csv_path, subset):
    data = pd.read_csv(csv_path, delimiter=' ', header=None)
    keys = []
    key_labels = []
    for i in range(data.shape[0]):
        row = data.iloc[i, :]
        slash_rows = data.iloc[i, 0].split('/')
        class_name = slash_rows[0]
        basename = slash_rows[1].split('.')[0]

        keys.append(basename)
        key_labels.append(class_name)
```

I tried suggestion here similar to my question like adding  on_bad_lines='skip' but nothing worked for me

any idea what can I do ?

and the classid file that I want to converted have this structure for each line

```
 1 CallCellphone
 2 cheerUp
 3 drink
 4 eat
 5 layDownOnSofa
 6 playGame
 7 playGuitar
 8 readBook
 9 sitDown
10 sitStill
11 standUp
12 tossPaper
13 useLaptop
14 useVacuumCleaner 
15 walk
16 writeOnAPpaper
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: the main idea is that I want to convert txt files into json format files and I've tried it using the script in the link  but for some reason I got the above error while reading the files with pd.read_csv and in this line it seems that' expection 2 arguments but it found 3

Answer (score 0):

usually, when this error occurs, the problem is the delimiter, try checking out the file that you are opening with pd.read_csv() and make sure they are separated by one space or tabs or commas and so on, then change the delimiter=' ' to delimiter='\t' or ',', or spaces, etc accordingly if needed.